# Why is a dereference " * " operator used in the function name?

Tags: c++

I have been currently taking this introductory programming course offered by stanford online, CS106B. In the Linked List structure the professor implemented this code which I am unable to wrap my head around.

```
 Entry *GetNewEntry(){

    cout << "Enter name (ENTER to quit):";
    string name = GetLine();
    if (name == "") return NULL;
    Entry *newOne = new Entry; // allocate in heap
    newOne->name = name;
    cout << "Enter address: ";
    newOne->address = GetLine();
    cout << "Enter phone: ";
    newOne->phone = GetLine();
    newOne->next = NULL; // no one follows
    return newOne;
}
```

Can anyone please help me understand why is there an dereference operator before a function name. What would change if we removed that?
I have tried to google it but I haven't received any satisfactory
answers.

Comment: `Entry *GetNewEntry()` could also be written as `Entry* GetNewEntry()`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: It certainly does, now that I know what it means. But I was having a hard time comprehending, it was written in the handouts the exact same way and I simply copied.

Comment: Whitespace positioning is usually pretty loose in C and C++. Here is a great tool for helping figure out what "gibberish" really means: https://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of the function `GetNewEntry` is a pointer of type `Entry *`.

If you removed the `*` from the code as is, you would end up returning a `Entry` instead, and the code would fail to compile, since `newOne` is a `Entry *`.

Comment: so, Entry here is a struct ...and GetNewEntry returns a pointer of type Entry. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ikaa1991 `Entry` is something. Could be an alias to an `int` and the result is the same: Pointer to `Entry`. EDIT The preceding is not completely clear. In this case Entry IS a `struct` or a `class` (not much difference between the two in C++). The point I was trying to make is it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It's a type called 'pointer to Entry'. It is suggested to put the asterisk next to the type name for easy understanding.

```
//suggested to put the asterisk next to type name
Entry* GetNewEntry(){...
}

//it's ok to put next to function name too
Entry *GetNewEntry(){...
}
```

Let's say `Entry` is a struct, then the size of an `Entry` variable will be the sum of sizes of properties. However, `Entry*` is a pointer to an `Entry` struct, and it is constantly of 4-byte size (32bit system), or 8-byte size (64bit system), whatever the number of properties inside the struct.

Edit:
The suggested declaration is easier to understand but it looks wrong in this case:

```
//a is pointer, b is Entry
Entry* a,b;
```

Solution is to declare each pointer variable on its own line:

```
//a is pointer, b is pointer
Entry* a;
Entry* b;
```

Comment: @SalehMahmood He wants to emphasise on good format. Instead of Entry "*"GetNewEntry() we should have used Entry"*" GetNewEntry(). The latter is easy to comprehend. Elaborating , the return type is a pointer to type Entry.

Comment: @datdinhquoc Just to clarify; suppose we do pointer arithmetic and asked for the value of b+1 what will be the result? take in this case the pointer entry* b

Comment: It is *not* 'suggested' to put the asterisk next to the type name. It binds syntactically to the following identifier, not the preceding type. Consider `Entry *a,b;`. If it was written `Entry* a,b;` it would suggest that `b` is a pointer, and it isn't. This is the reason for the practice the OP is asking about.

Comment: @user207421 Can you elaborate? I can't figure out what  are you trying to imply

Comment: @Ikaa1991 In `Entry *a,b`, `a` is a pointer to `Entry`, but `b` *is* an `Entry`.

Comment: i usually declare each variable on a new line, and not facing the `Entry *a,b` issue :)

Comment: @datdinhquoc Certainly, me too, but nevertheless it illustrates the point. It is the *variable* that is the pointer, not the *type*. In this case it is the *function* that returns the pointer. You will note that the OP's code also has `Entry *newOne = new Entry;`, and again this is normal.